# Static text above horizontally scrollable table in shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have a basic shiny app with `rhandsontable`. The table is wide so while rendering the output, there is a horizontal scroll available in the table. Example below:

[image]

Now, for this table, I want to display a static content above the last 4 columns of the table like below:

[image]

The problem I am facing is when I scroll towards left, the text follows the scroll. Issue below:

[image]

Please carefully notice the location of scroll with respect to the table and text. The code to reproduce the issues is below:

```
if(interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(rhandsontable)
  library(dplyr)
  
  ui <- fluidPage(br(),
                  br(),
                  
                  fluidRow(column(
                    12,
                    div(style = "text-align:right; margin-right:50px", "Show text here Only")
                  ),
                  column(12, rHandsontableOutput("mytable"))))
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$mytable <- renderRHandsontable({
      data <-
        mtcars %>% cbind(mtcars) %>% cbind(mtcars) %>% cbind(mtcars) %>% head(10)
      rhandsontable(data, strecH = "all")
    })
    
  }
  
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

I am not sure if there is any extension on rhandsontable for this or if this could be resolved just using css or javascript alone. The width of the table could vary based on the data and length of individual columns.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand. You say "the text follows the scroll", but in the two images it is at the same position. It has not moved.

Comment: I mean that I want the text above the last 4 columns and it should not be above any other part of the table. Now the position of the text is static as per the column width and is visible on the page. I want it to be hidden from the initial part and shown above the last 4 columns only.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I understood later. And I tried, unsuccessfully. The better way would be a grouped header for these 4 columns. I think it's possible with the JavaScript library **handsontable**, but not with **rhandsontable**. It's possible with **DT**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution *partially works*. The problem is that the horizontal scrollbar of the table disappears, but there is a scrollbar at the very bottom of the screen.

```r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(), br(),
  div(
    style = "position: absolute;",
    div(
      style = "position: relative; width: auto; float: right;",
      tags$p(
        style = 
          "position: absolute; left: 80%; right: 0; top: 0; width: 150px; height: 50px; transform: translateX(-100%);", 
        "Show text here Only"
      ),
    ),
    div(
      style = "clear: right; height: 5px;"
    ),
    br(), br(),
    rHandsontableOutput("mytable")
  )      
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytable <- renderRHandsontable({
    data <-
      mtcars %>% cbind(mtcars) %>% cbind(mtcars) %>% cbind(mtcars) %>% head(10)
    rhandsontable(data, stretchH = "all")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

## EDIT: working solution!

```r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(), br(),
  div(
    style = "border: solid 1px black; overflow-x: scroll;",
    div(
      style = "display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: fit-content;",
      div(
        style = "display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse; overflow-x: hidden;",
        tags$p(
          "Show text here Only"
        )
      ),
      rHandsontableOutput("mytable")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytable <- renderRHandsontable({
    data <-
      mtcars %>% cbind(mtcars) %>% cbind(mtcars) %>% cbind(mtcars) %>% head(10)
    rhandsontable(data) %>% hot_table(stretchH = "all", overflow = "hidden")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Stéphane for the answer. It works well and precisely what was required.